# How can I connect to a specific access point in a group having the same SSID?

Tags: wi-fi, android-10

I'm on Android 10 and I have a WiFi network with multiple access points, each one with 2.4 and 5 GHz, everything with the same SSID to let the phones pick the best one.

However android has a too low threshold for switching network: sometimes the signal is poor because I'm still connected to the same AP even if I moved around, while a much stronger signal would be available.

With the app "WiFi connection manager" I can list all access points within a WiFi network but by clicking on one the connection fails. I think it's an issue with Android 10, since this was exactly the point of the app, together with automatic switching according to custom rules.

The only workaround I found is to manually disable and enable again the WiFi, which results in a connection to the strongest access point, which is nevertheless not the best one, since the 5 GHz network from each access point is often a bit weaker power-wise, but it would nevertheless grant much higher speed.

Is there a way to connect to a specific access point, which implies also specific frequency?

No root privileges available, android 10 stock.

Comment: Why not use different SSIDs?

Comment: @alecxs well roaming between different access points takes place automatically when the signal is poor, while changing network takes place when the previous one is lost, which means I get better "worst" signal this way. My point is to forcefully change AP before that threshold is reached, to improve further. See also https://superuser.com/questions/362366/does-it-make-sense-to-keep-different-ssids-for-2-4ghz-and-5ghz-wireless-networks

Comment: My main router Xiaomi AC2100 kicks devices out of 2.4 GHz if it thinks they would get better speed on 5 GHz, but I think that functionality is not in firmware and was lost when I installed OpenWRT. Also, the other AP used as repeaters don't have that functionality anyway, they are AC1200.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I trust the OS's ability to switch access points more than the router's Roaming Assist feature. So try turning this off on the router.

Additionally, many routers have a Smart Connect feature. This switches a device from one band to another band. You could try turning that off too.

If it still doesn't work, then I guess it's Android's fault. A workaround is to create 2 separate SSIDs for 2.4 and 5 GHz. Then just use the 5 GHz SSID.
It's likely that the 2.4 SSID doesn't confer any benefits, even range (at target throughput), so just don't use it.